# Can RegEx have an OR function

Tags: regex

I have string of text that follows the format below.

```
code (family) - LongName (ShortName)
```

I want to parse out "ShortName" and the following works

```
\).*\(([^\)]+)\)
```

but if I use the above RegEx
on an unformatted line of text it returns blank. I'd rather it return the unformatted string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is unanchored, and the match can occur in the middle of the string.

If there can be a single match, you could prepend an anchor, and in the alternation `|` match the whole line.

```php
^.*\).*?\(([^\)\n]+)\)|^.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7QkdM8/1)

If there can be more matches, you could make the dot non greedy `.*?` to not only get the last occurence, and only match the whole line if the pattern does not occur using a negative lookahead.

```php
\).*?\(([^\)\n]+)\)|^(?!.*\).*?\(([^\)\n]+)\)).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGSAf3/1)

Comment: The tool I am using doesn't like either of the recommendation above. I keep getting an error on non-formatted text. It finds the desired text if it is formatted.

Comment: @acr_scout What it the tool or language?

Comment: I am using it with a program called Nitro Studio, it is an InfoPath replacement for SharePoint.

Comment: @acr_scout So you mean that if there is a match for the capture group it works. But if there is not match for the capture group, you get an error?

Comment: The Fourth bird you are correct.

Comment: @acr_scout I am not familiar with that tool, but reading [this page](https://www.crowcanyon.help/article/comprehensive-list-of-functions-in-nitro-studio/) I think it uses the capture group 1 for the replacement. I am not sure if it returns only group 1, or other groups as well. You could try `\).*\(([^\)]+)\)|^(?!.*\).*?\([^\)\n]+\).*)(.+)` Or else maybe use replace, and then use group 1 in the replacement `^.*\).*\(([^\)]+)\).*$`

Comment: Making as answered because my issue may be a limitation of the tool I am using.